# ListView not clickable even with descendantFocusability

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, clickable

I'm trying to implement a ContextMenu, but by doing so I checked that my listview was not clickable.

I went over different threads based on this subject and tried everything proposed `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` 
even 
`descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
but still not working

Here is my main xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".HomePage">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnAddTask"
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="goToAddTask" />

    <ListView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewTasks"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddTask"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTaskList"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtTaskList"
        android:id="@+id/txtTaskList"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my list_item xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:src="@drawable/no_cross"
        android:onClick="goToDeleteTask"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="Delete button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/txtTaskListName"
        android:id="@+id/txtTaskListName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/txtTaskListDate"
        android:id="@+id/txtTaskListDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTaskListName"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/txtTaskListTime"
        android:id="@+id/txtTaskListTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTaskListName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtTaskListDate"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally my java code:

```
public class HomePage extends ActionBarActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ListView taskListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Task> taskAdapter;

    int longClickedItemIndex;

    List<Task> Tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        taskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);

        // The following piece of code allows to empty database before testing when reinstalling the app for test.
        //getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("myTasks");

        registerForContextMenu(taskListView);

        taskListView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        taskListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemIndex = position;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (dbHandler.getTasksCount() != 0)
            Tasks.addAll(dbHandler.getAllTasks());

        populateTasksList();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

        public TaskListAdapter(){
            super(HomePage.this, R.layout.tasklist_item, Tasks);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
            if (view == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tasklist_item, parent, false);
            }

            Task currentTask = Tasks.get(position);

            TextView taskListName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskListName);
            taskListName.setText(currentTask.getTitle());
            TextView taskListDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskListDate);
            taskListDate.setText(currentTask.getDate());
            TextView taskListTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskListTime);
            taskListTime.setText(currentTask.getTime());
            /*ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            //deleteButton.setTag(currentTask.getId());
            deleteButton.setTag(R.id.taskId,currentTask.getId());
            deleteButton.setTag(R.id.position,position);*/

            return view;
        }
    }

    private void populateTasksList() {
        taskAdapter = new TaskListAdapter();
        taskListView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
    }

    public void goToAddTask(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTask.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void goToDeleteTask(final View view){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                // Set Dialog Icon
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bullet_key_permission)
                        // Set Dialog Title
                .setTitle(R.string.removeAlert)
                        // Set Dialog Message
                .setMessage(R.string.deleteMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

                        // Retrieving the task to delete
                        int taskId = (int) deleteButton.getTag(R.id.taskId);
                        Task taskToDelete = dbHandler.getTask(taskId);

                        // Removing the task from the database and from the calendar
                        dbHandler.deleteTask(taskToDelete, context);

                        // Removing the task from the listView
                        TaskListAdapter tAdapter = (TaskListAdapter)taskListView.getAdapter();
                        int position = (int)deleteButton.getTag(R.id.position);
                        tAdapter.remove(tAdapter.getItem(position));
                        tAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.removedTask, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                    }
                })
                .create();

        alertDialog.show();

    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.edit_pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.contextMenu_title);
        menu.add(menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, R.string.contextMenu_edit);
        menu.add(menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, R.string.contextMenu_delete);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                // TODO : Implement editing a task
                break;
            case DELETE:
                deleteTask();

                //TODO : to be tested
                /*
                dbHandler.deleteTask(Tasks.get(longClickedItemIndex);
                Tasks.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 */
                break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void deleteTask(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                // Set Dialog Icon
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bullet_key_permission)
                        // Set Dialog Title
                .setTitle(R.string.removeAlert)
                        // Set Dialog Message
                .setMessage(R.string.deleteMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

                        // Retrieving the task to delete
                        int taskId = (int) deleteButton.getTag(R.id.taskId);
                        Task taskToDelete = dbHandler.getTask(taskId);

                        // Removing the task from the database and from the calendar
                        dbHandler.deleteTask(taskToDelete, context);

                        // Removing the task from the listView
                        TaskListAdapter tAdapter = (TaskListAdapter) taskListView.getAdapter();
                        int position = (int) deleteButton.getTag(R.id.position);
                        tAdapter.remove(tAdapter.getItem(position));
                        tAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.removedTask, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .create();

        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

(2 delete functions, cause of my test I'm currently performing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally tried several things and find my solution (for whom it could be usefull).

First of all I had to remove all the things related to "clickable" attribute from all my xml

Then, if you check my list item xml, I have 2 layouts (2 linear one, don't know if this could be different with Relative, did not test this).
What I did is to remove the second one, and modify the core LinearLayout to Relative Layout (to display my elements as I want).

Then I launched again my app and it's perfectly working.